# How long is it best to arrive at the airport before the flight?

Tags: airports

For a UK to France flight with online check-in and without hold luggage, with FlyBe, how long should I be at the airport before my flight if I don't want to wait too much?

Comment: Depends on the airport and airline. 20 min might be enough, 1.5 to 2 hours should be comfortable everywhere.

Comment: This is kinda broad.

Comment: I thought I was rather specific actually :) Maybe I don't realize, I'm really not an expert.

Comment: @drake035 other crucial pieces of context: How full is the flight?/How likely is it to be overbooked? or get you bumped? (very common in the US, by comparison) How early must you be at gate (not checkin) in order to be eligible for bumping compensation? How reliable/unreliable is your transport/traffic? And when you say "arrive at the airport", do you mean "park in the long-term car park" or "arrive at checkin"? Assuming you check in online and preprint your boarding pass (is that reliable?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really a personal preference, depending on many factors, including the length of and likely variability in your journey to the airport, knowledge of the airport, the time of departure, day of week and season. Most crucially, how stressed or relaxed you would like to feel before you fly.

The most variable and uncontrollable factors that will affect you will be parking (if relevant), and the security queue.

45 minutes should be ample, 30 minutes would be cutting it fine but I would recommend planning on arriving an hour before to ensure a stress free departure.